# SharePoint 2010 Workflow - Check field every 48 hours and send email if necessary

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow

My customer has a list of problem tickets in SharePoint. When a new ticket item is created, they want the system to check every 48 hours if the item has been modified in the last 48 hours, and send an email if it has not been modified.

I created a workflow that pauses 48 hours at the start, and checks the modified date/time, and sends an email, but I can't figure out how to make the workflow loop back and start the 48 hour wait again.  Is this possible in SharePoint Designer?

Comment: Are you stick to SharePoint Designer? Can you create some c# code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a helper workflow that restarts the first workflow after it ends, creating a loopback senario.  I did it something like this:

Workflow 1:
-Pause 48 hours
-Do logic check - send email if needed
-Update currentItem.WFStatus (hidden column) to 'LoopBack' to force Workflow 2 to start
-End Workflow 1

Workflow 2:
-Wait for WFStatus to equal 'LoopBack'
-Update currentItem.WFStatus to 'Restart' to force Workflow 1 to restart
-End Workflow 2

They call this CoRecursion, which I found a guide on here:
[Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sharepointdesigner/service-pack-2-prevents-an-on-change-workflow-from-starting-itself)

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it with Sharepoint Designer, but you can create powershell script that will start your workflow and schedule it with Windows Task Scheduler to start every 48 hours. Here is an example of such script: http://www.mysharepointadventures.com/2012/06/start-a-workflow-using-powershell/